# Using SQL to create football fixtures?

Tags: php, sql

Quite hard to explain but say I have a table named 'Teams' and It contains 5 teams like so:

```
 team_id, teamname, manager
   1,       Team1,    1
   2,       Team2,    10
   3,       Team3,    3
   4,       Team4,    5
   5,       Team5,    6
```

I need to create another table looking similar to this (named TeamFixtures for example)

```
  id, HomeTeam, HomeScore, AwayScore, AwayTeam
                  NULL        NULL
```

How would I make the HomeTeam and AwayTeam be the team_id of the 'teams' table?

Id need this for each team so they play against each other twice, home and away games.

Is there a Query that could make this quicker for me, rather than typing out the fixtures 1by1

Comment: how will you know that a certain team is  `hometeam` or `awayteam`?

Comment: I don't understand, They play each other twice so one is always going to be an away team and one always home.  1 would play 2, then 2 would play 1. lol hard to explain :S

Comment: Sounds like homework to me...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When an attribute of a relation is they key of another relation, it is called a [Foreign Key](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Foreign_key).

In the case of your `TeamFixtures` table, you would have two foreign keys `hometeam` and `awayteam`.

Your `CREATE` statement would look like:

```
CREATE TABLE teamfixtures(
    ...
    hometeam INT,
    awayteam INT,
    ...
    CONSTRAINT fk_hometeam FOREIGN KEY(hometeam) REFERENCES teams, 
    CONSTRAINT fk_awayteam FOREIGN KEY(awayteam) REFERENCES teams,
    CONSTRAINT ck_teams CHECK(hometeam <> awayteam)
    )
```

Comment: +1 don't forget you will need a unique and composite key on `hometeam` and `awayteam` columns so they cannot play each other

Comment: @AlexP ahh yes.. A check should cover that though.